# Android Broadcast receiver with multiple actions

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

How should I implement a broadcast receiver & filter so that it can response to multiple `intents`.

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver;
IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
```

onCreate():

```
    myFilter.addAction("first");
    myFilter.addAction("second");

    myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // do different actions according to the intent
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, myFilter);
```

from my fragment:

```
Intent i = new Intent("first"); sendBroadcast(i);

Intent i = new Intent("second"); sendBroadcast(i);
```

Thanks

Comment: just look at the action in the intent `intent.getAction()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null) {
        if(action.equals("action1") {
            // CODE
        } else if (action.equals("action2") {
            // CODE
        }
    }
}
```